# searching for keywords in a directory of powerpoints

Tags: python, powerpoint

I am trying to create a python program to search powerpoint slides for a keyword. This is what I have so far but I keep getting an error telling me that it is looking for a zip file "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"
Thank you

```
from pptx import Presentation
import os

def main():

    while(True):
        search = input("Keyword: ")
        result = []
        for filename in os.listdir():
            f = open(filename)
            pres = Presentation(f)
            for slide in pres.slides:
                for shape in slide.shapes:
                    if not shape.has_text_frame:
                        continue
                    for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                        for run in paragraph.runs:
                            if search in run.text:
                                result.append(run.text)
                                result.append(" - ")
                                result.append(filename)
                            else:
                                continue
            f.close()
            print(result)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What you have are PPT files, not PPTX files. You need a library that reads those. `pptx` only supports the XML files in a ZIP archive format.

Comment: I am using pptx files. And can you elaborate on what you mean that the pptx library only supports XML files in a zip archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to open the file before passing it to `Presentation()`. Simply pass the filename.

```
prs = Presentation(filename)
```

Also make sure that all the files you use that way are in fact PPTX files, perhaps with a few lines that look like:

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    if not filename.endswith('.pptx'):
        continue
    prs = Presentation(filename)
```

If you did want to use open files for some reason, you need to open them in binary mode:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
```

Comment: I believe this worked but I got a different error stating "package not found at 'pres.pptx'" any ideas?

Comment: `print` out your filenames to make sure you're getting the ones you expect. Your `os.listdir()` call is expecting a parameter and you may need to manipulate the paths you get back in order to point `Presentation()` at the right relative path. The default path in Python can be tricky.